# How to remove first character from featureclass in Python?

Tags: arcpy

I have a bunch of feature classes in a geodatabase that start with an underscore and want to remove it, but ONLY the first instance.  See below:
e.g. _COGCC_W_S --> want it to be COGCC_W_S

I have a script written to find and replace but it keeps replace all values instead of only the FIRST instance.  I thought fc.replace(oldString, newString, 1) should work but it keeps removing all underscores.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
findString = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1) 
newString = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2) 

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses() 

for fc in fcList: 
    if fc.startswith(findString):
        arcpy.Rename_management(fc, fc.replace(findString, newString, 1))
```

Comment: I think you will find many questions on [so] that will help you answer this pure Python question. Your string happens to be a feature class name but it could be the name of anything.

Comment: You can use the `re` module to remove the first occurrence of "_": `r = re.sub("_", "", "_COGCC_W_S", 1)`. Or simply slice the string if you are sure the character will be the first character every time: `"_COGCC_W_S"[1:]`.

Comment: @Aaron _if you are sure the character will be the first character every time_ - if only there was a way to check this ;)

Comment: To see that this is a pure Python rather than GIS library question try replacing `arcpy.Rename_management(fc, fc.replace(findString, newString, 1)` with `print(fc, fc.replace(findString, newString, 1)` in your code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `re` module's `re.sub` to replace the first instance of "_" in a string. This would be the safest method if you are unsure if there will be any characters in front of the underscore. Otherwise, slicing the string would work if you are certain the underscore will be the first character every time.

```
import re

my_string = "_COGCC_W_S"

# Method 1: Using the re module to replace the first occurance of "_"
re.sub("_", "", my_string, 1)

# Method 2: Slicing the string to eliminate first character
my_string[1:]
```

Comment: how about if fc[0:1] == '_': fc = fc[1:] or variants thereof? Isn't this just simple string manipulation?